# how to get all field data from salesforce object using any object id without soql

Tags: apex

I need any field data from any object by passing object id dynamically so can anyone tell me how to get all field data from salesforce object using any object id without using soql?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: whats ur complete use case ? r u doing this in apex or any external application ? and why without soql ?

Comment: Actually i have to get values for some fields dynamically to visualforce page using id

Answer (score 2):

In controller you can do like below:

```
public without sharing class CreateCaseExtension2 
{
 public CaseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller)
 {

 this.caseObj = (Case)stdcontroller.getRecord();
 if(caseObj.Id != null){
 caseObj = getAllCaseFields();
 }}

// Case all fields return
private Case getAllCaseFields(){
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMap = schema.SObjectType.Case.fields.getMap();
    List<Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMapValues = fldObjMap.values();

    String theQuery = 'SELECT ';
    for(Schema.SObjectField s : fldObjMapValues)
    {
       String theName = s.getDescribe().getName();

       // Continue building your dynamic query string
       theQuery += theName + ',';
    }

    // Trim last comma
    theQuery = theQuery.subString(0, theQuery.length() - 1);

    // Finalize query string
    theQuery += ' FROM Case WHERE Id = \''+ caseObj.Id +'\'';

    // Make your dynamic call
    List<Case> caseList = Database.query(theQuery);
    return caseList[0];
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to achieve this in your trigger then you can do something like below.

```
Public Static Void ProposalAuditLog1(List<Object__c> ObjIds)
{ 
    List<New_Object__c> NOList  = new list<New_Object__c>();
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> SchemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType ObjSchema = SchemaMap.get('Object__c');
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> FieldMap = ObjSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();//This has the list of all field names.
    system.debug('-----FieldMap-----'+FieldMap);


//In the FOR loop id's can be passed without using SOQL.
    for (String FieldName: FieldMap.keySet()) 
    {                    
        for(Object__c APP : ObjIds)
        {
             If( FieldName != 'lastmodifieddate' && FieldName != 'systemmodstamp'){
             If(Trigger.oldMap.get(APP.id).get(FieldName) != Trigger.newMap.get(APP.id).get(FieldName))
             {
                 New_Object__c X = new New_Object__c();

                 X.Field1__c = APP.Id;
                 X.Field2__c = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();
                 X.Field3__c = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel()+' value has been modified from '+Trigger.oldMap.get(APP.id).get(FieldName)+' to '+Trigger.newMap.get(APP.id).get(FieldName)+'.' ;
                 NOList.add(X);
             }}
        }
    }
    Insert PDALList;
}
```

Hope this helps.